# Selecting partial data for day based on when column value meets condition

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2010. My SQL knowledge is limited and I haven't been able to figure out how to code the following rules.

I have a datetime column that I sort by datetime and then group by date (using group by int(datetime).

Now I want to select records within each date up to and including the point a condition is met. Once condition is met, then that record with all preceding records will be returned as the record set for that day. Records for that date following a matching condition will be ignored.

My data has:

```
Trade  DateTime           Points  CumPoints
1   11/20/2015 9:31 AM      2       2
2   11/20/2015 9:49 AM      1       3
3   11/20/2015 9:55 AM      1.25    4.25
4   11/20/2015 10:20 AM     -1.5    2.75  -- record ignored
5   11/20/2015 10:21 AM     -0.75   2  -- record ignored
6   11/20/2015 10:36 AM      5.25   7.25  -- record ignored
1   11/23/2015 9:30 AM       2      2
2   11/23/2015 10:07 AM     -1.25   0.75
3   11/23/2015 10:29 AM      0.5    1.25
4   11/23/2015 11:07 AM     -1.25   0
5   11/23/2015 11:23 AM     -0.25   -0.25 -- record ignored
6   11/23/2015 12:53 PM     -1      -1.25 -- record ignored
```

So if my rules are that once Cum-points >=4 or if Cum-points <= 0 after 11:00 AM then those records are returned. In the above example the query should return the first 3 records for the first date and the first 4 records for the 2nd date.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That could be like this:

```
Select 
    DateValue([DateTime]) As [Date], Points, CumPoints
From
    YourTable
Having
    (CumPoints >= 4) 
        Or 
    (TimeValue([DateTime]) > #11:00:00 AM# 
    And
    CumPoints <= 0)
Group By
    DateValue([DateTime]) As [Date], Points, CumPoints
```

You will have to adjust as your sample data don't correlate with your description of the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My textual description is correct, but my graphic of the data was not correct in that I didn't "highlight" to ignore the 4th record on the first day.  The solution you provided isn't giving me what I was hoping. Working with just the first condition, once the cumpoints hits 4, then all following records regardless of the value of cumpoints should be ignored. (cumpoints is really the sum of points). Your solution gave me records where one of the solutions was met (i.e. cumpoints was >=4) but didn't give me for example the very first record.

Comment: But where does the 11:00 AM come in? Conditions must be very clear.

Comment: I was just trying to shorten the problem with just clarifying scenario 1. Scenario 2 is that if cumpoints <= 0 after 11am then stop processing records for that day. So with my above data on day 2, cumpoints =0 at 11:07am. So for day 2 the query would return records 1-4. If either scenario occurs, then the record set returned for that day are the records up until the condition occurred. All subsequent records for that day are not part of the record set. I appreciate your review of this problem.

Comment: If I was using flat files, I would open the source file, do some looping on for each day and for each record determine if the record was good to keep. If good then I would add the record to a 2nd temporary file (or a link list). Once a condition was met, I would back out of the loops to start a new day of processing. I'm thinking I might need to do this via VBA but I don't know how to do the mechanics of passing back that final resultant set to the Access Report.

Comment: Then I believe the simplest method is to loop the recordset in VB and mark a new field with True for those records to select.